# Creating Azure ExpressRoute Connections via CLI: Error: ID was missing the expressRouteGateways element

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to create an azure expressroute connection using the Azure CLI, however there appears to be a discrepancy between the ExpressRoute Gateway Id as required by the API and the ExpresRoute Gateway ID as provided via the portal:

The portal provides the ER gw id as:

```
"/subscriptions/319b5c03-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/hk-connectivity-eastasia/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways/hk-ergw-eastasia"
```

However the azure cli seems to want:

```
"/subscriptions/319b5c03-xxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/hk-connectivity-eastasia/providers/Microsoft.Network/expressRouteGateways/hk-ergw-eastasia"
```

(or at least something containing "expressRouteGateways" )

So we get the error:

```
**az network express-route gateway connection create --gateway-name /subscriptions/REDACTED/resourceGroups/hk-connectivity-eastasia/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworkGateways/hk-ergw-eastasia --name hk-nprd-erc-000 --resource-group hk-connectivity-eastasia --circuit-name er-expressroute-ea-nprd-erc-hub00-net --peering AzurePrivatePeering


ERROR: (ResourceNotFound) 

The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/expressRouteGateways/subscriptions' 

under resource group 'hk-connectivity-eastasia' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix

Code: ResourceNotFound

Message: The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/expressRouteGateways/subscriptions' under resource group 'hk-connectivity-eastasia' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
+ OUT=
+ printf 'connection creation result: \n'
connection creation result:
```

I can't seem to find this as a known bug or related issue though.

Attempt #2:

CLI:

```
az network express-route gateway connection create \
  --gateway-name hk-ergw-eastasia \ 
  --name hk-nonprod-erconn-000 \ 
  --peering /subscriptions/REDACTED/resourceGroups/hk-connectivity-eastasia/providers/Microsoft.Network/expressRouteCircuits/hk-nonprod/peerings/AzurePrivatePeering \
  --resource-group hk-connectivity-eastasia
```

Result:

```
++ az network express-route gateway connection create --gateway-name hk-ergw-eastasia --name hk-nonprod-erconn-000 --peering /subscriptions/REDACTED/resourceGroups/hk-connectivity-eastasia/providers/Microsoft.Network/expressRouteCircuits/hk-nonprod/peerings/AzurePrivatePeering --resource-group hk-connectivity-eastasia
ERROR: (ResourceNotFound) The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/expressRouteGateways/hk-ergw-eastasia' under resource group 'hk-connectivity-eastasia' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
Code: ResourceNotFound
Message: The Resource 'Microsoft.Network/expressRouteGateways/hk-ergw-eastasia' under resource group 'hk-connectivity-eastasia' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix
```

Troubleshooting notes:

1. The ER Circuit is up and running
2. BGP routes are being exchanged between the ISP and on-premises
3. BGP routes to the Hub VNET and spoke VNETs attached to the ER gateway are being propagated to on-prem
4. BGP peering is therefore fine.

Comment: I've logged an issue for this at Azure's github as I believe this is an issue with the Azure API for Exressroute Gateways/Virtual Network Gateway: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/24984#issuecomment-1367702526

Answer (score 0):

In order to create azure network express route to gateway connection, use below script.

You can get the  **Azure Gateway Name**  in Portal, like below.

**Azure Portal > Virtual network gateways > Select your Gate Way**

[image]

**Here is the script to create a Azure ExpressRoute Connections**

```
az network express-route gateway connection create --gateway-name MyGateway --name MyExpressRouteConnection --peering /subscriptions/MySub/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/provi ders/Microsoft.Network/expressRouteCircuits/MyCircuit/peerings/AzurePrivatePeering --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

Reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/express-route/gateway/connection?view=azure-cli-latest#az-network-express-route-gateway-connection-create

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, the same issue occurs. I've updated the output in my question.

Comment: BGP peering is fine. The problem is with the API. I've logged an issue with MS.

Comment: I suspect Microsoft has misnamed the resource in the API or not updated it's api documentation. See the currently open github issue I posted in my original question.